# Getting HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request from ASP .NET 4.6.1 even while using JSON.stringify

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Here is each section. I've read all the questions about using `JSON.stringify()` but none have worked for me. I've also tried *not* using `JSON.stringify()` and `contentType: 'application/json'`, but I get the same 400 error.

If I leave the JavaScript AJAX the same, it works in the first example, with parameters listed out in the `SendEmailAPI` action, but it does *not* work when I try to let it map to a view model.

#### ASP 4.61 MVC Controller that works with each parameter listed out.

```
public class HomeController : Place.Web.Mvc.BaseController
{
...
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendEmailAPI(string FormType, string FirstName, string LastName, string GLobalOrCampusId)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
     ...
```

#### ASP 4.61 MVC Controller that does **not** work with a view model.

```
public class HomeController : Place.Web.Mvc.BaseController
{
...
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendEmailAPI(FormViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
     ...
```

#### The jQuery AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/SendEmailAPI',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'FirstName': self.firstName(),
        'LastName': self.lastName(),
        'GlobalOrCampusId': self.globalOrCampusId(),
        'FormType': self.formType()
    }),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Success:', data);

    },
    error: function (data) {
        $('#tempErrorSpot').append(data.responseText)
        console.warn('Error:', data);

    }
})
```

#### The ViewModel

```
namespace Place.Request.ViewModels
{
    public class FormViewModel : Place.Web.Mvc.BaseViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Type of Form")]
        [Required]
        public string FormType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Global ID or Campus ID")]
        public string GlobalOrCampusId { get; set; }  

        [Required]
        public string Department { get; set; }

        public string ResponseMessage { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Http 400 just a general error code that means the request wasn't in the right format, you need to do more diagnostics before anyone will be able to help you. I recommend you check out the http request in the network inspector in your browsers development tools.

Comment: Thanks @Simon I'll, try to update this with how I can get it to work just fine with parameters, but when i switch to the viewModel it grows in 400 thwarting angry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation was that after trying it with string parameters and having it work, that I looked a little closer at the `if (ModelState.IsValid)`.

Debugging on the server, **ModelState.Values.5.Errors.0.ErrorMessage** showed *"The Department field is required."* Problem revealed!

Turns out that I had `[Required]` fields on the **FormViewModel** that weren't yet being populated (I just hadn't implemented them on the UI yet).  The generic `HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)` was returned later in the `ModelState.IsValid` `else` statement's  logic branch.